# Unable to install native extensions on digitalocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, digital-ocean

When i use the command `bundle install` on in terminal (whilst i'm connected to digital oceans server) I keep getting this error.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151226-8411-15s6u34.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [generator.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2 

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
```

and this is for most of the gems however their all slightly different, but all of them say "Failed to build gem native extension". I've looked everywhere and i'm not entirely sure of what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that the error occurred in `json-1.8.3` gem and thus try

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

and then again `bundle install` and see if it is fixed.